# AJAX return PHP data to page

Tags: php, ajax

#### Edit

I've changed my approach based on some research, and I'm getting a partial result.

Database:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  id  |  date      |  objet  |  contenu     | lu  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1   | 2013-01-20 | msg1    | msg1_content | 0   |
|  2   | 2013-01-20 | msg2    | msg2_content | 0   |
|  3   | 2013-01-20 | msg3    | msg3_content | 0   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="markAsRead('.$message['id'].');">View'</a>
```

JS/AJAX:

```
function markAsRead(id)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'php/messagerie.php',
        data: "id=" + id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ ur backend side
        success: function(data)
        {
            // data is ur summary
            $('#contenu').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP (php/messagerie.php)

```
$q = intval($_GET['id']);

// connect to db (of course not shown here)
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM coq_messagerie WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$lu = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."messagerie SET lu='1' WHERE id='$q' LIMIT 1");
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>objet</th>
            <th>contenu</th>
            <th>lu</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['objet'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['contenu'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['lu'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

I'm currently only retrieving only the `<th>`'s and not information when I'm looking up for `id` 2 or 3, but am getting information for `id` 1. How can this be only partially working?

---

#### Introduction

In an attempt to show dynamic information on my page, I'm using a mix of a few bits and pieces of code which should collect data from a basic HTML link which parses and returns data on the current page. Of course, this seems very basic, but being my first AJAX script, I would greatly appreciate some help.

#### Code

HTML Link:

```
$output .= '<a onclick="markAsRead('.$message['id'].'); return false;">'.View.'</a>';
```

*Note: The link collects the `id` field as expected.*

JS/AJAX Code:

```
function markAsRead(str) {
    console.log("starting");
    if (str=="")
    {
        console.log("string empty");
        document.getElementById("contenu").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        console.log("on ready state change");
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("contenu").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("seems to returning information");
            var abc = "<h1>Huh.</h1>";
            document.getElementById("contenu").innerHTML=abc;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","php/messagerie.php?q="+str);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

*Note: The `console.log('###_'+str)` is used to see where the code crashes. All logged properly (105, 107, 109).*

PHP (*php/read.php*)

```
// connect to db (of course not shown here)
$message = $GET["messageid"];

$lu = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE messages SET lu='1' WHERE id='$message' LIMIT 1");
if(!$lu)
{
    echo "Update error"; 
    exit;
}
else
{    
    $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id='$message' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
        echo $row["contenu"];
    }
}
```

*Note: `$lu` is updated, which makes me believe the problem is either in the `while/echo` area or in my AJAX return.*

#### Current console logs

```
starting
on ready state change
seems to returning information
-> GET ***/php/messagerie.php?q=3
   ** params -> q 3 **
   ** empty response **
   ** empty HTML **
on ready state change
seems to returning information
on ready state change
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You could add a lot more output to the response returned from the PHP script to get feedback even it 0 rows are returned. add an echo before the while loop to say "results found: "; for example. Also could debug further adding extra onreadystatechange output. Currently you only capture when a result has completed and is successful. Add an } else { to the ready state callback that could populate another element with ALL response text.

Comment: @ArtofThem I've used your suggestion, I've added an else statement to the `readyState` condition and I do see some content flicker. I've edited the code above to reflect the new code with the flickr.

Comment: If it's showing then disappearing quickly it's likely the innerHTML is being set again AFTER the "Huh.". I would now add console logs to the beginning of the click handler; ie. above if (str=="") and check to see if the function is being triggered twice. Even add an additional log within the str=="" condition to check if the innerHTML is being set to empty.

Comment: Indeed, some elements are repeating. I've added newest code and current console logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found! This updates the field value to mark message as read and shows the message in the proper div.

### Solution

In the AJAX request, the missing parameter of **`true`** has been added with the query.

### Complete code

#### AJAX

```
function markAsRead(str)
{    
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("contenu").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("contenu").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","php/messagerie.php?q="+str,true);  // added ",true"
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

#### PHP

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('','','',''); // values hidden here for obvious reasons
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE messages SET lu='1' WHERE id='$q'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>objet</th>
                <th>contenu</th>
                <th>lu</th>
            </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['objet'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['contenu'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['lu'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = $GET["messageid"];
```

should be

```
$message = $_GET["messageid"];
```

Comment: I've done the change in my file, but this has not corrected the issue. Good point, though.

Comment: in your js conolse.log() the whole xhr response to give you some clues as to what your php is doing.